# Get all the images of the product from inside the product page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to scrape [this](https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1) page(main page), which i have done.

Now what i want is to scrape all the images by going inside the each product page.

So it should be like from main page going to product page downloading all product images, coming back to the main page then to the next product page and so on.

**I have used `requests` library, below is the code through which i get Name and Image from main page**

*How do i extend this code for getting images of product from product page*

```
url = 'https://middleware.paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}


payload = {
'channel': 'web',
'child_site_id': '6',
'site_id': '2',
'version': '2',
'discoverability': 'online',
'use_mw': '1',
'category': '101405',
'page': '1',
'page_count': '1',
'items_per_page': '32'}


#total pages needed
jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
total_count = jsonData['totalCount']
total_pages = total_count / 32
pages = math.ceil(total_pages)


from pandas import DataFrame

NAME = []
IMG = []

for page in range(1,pages + 1):
    payload.update({'page':page, 'page_count':page})

    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

    for product in jsonData['grid_layout']:
        name = product['name']
        img = product['image_url']

        print ('Name: %s\nImage: %s\n' %(name, img))

        NAME.append(name)
        IMG.append(img)
```

Ex: [this](https://paytmmall.com/tata-tea-premium-leaf-250gm-CMPLXFASTATA-TEA-PREZEPH705721FEE26D1F-pdp?product_id=247956476&channel=WEB&discoverability=online&src=grid&svc=-1&tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fg%2Ffmcg%2Ffoods-glpid-101405%7C101405%7C1%7C%7C%7C%7C&get_review_id=205609277) is the page of the 1st product from the main page and i want to download all the product images from there,then get back to the main page and move on to next product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge below code after `print ('Name: %s\nImage: %s\n' %(name, img))` statement,
it will download all images and saved at current script directory.
The image is saved with its `image name` as in specified URL.

```
imagename = img.split("/")[-1]
r = requests.get(img)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(imagename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

OR:

if you don't want to save image at current script directory, just want to image 
content try this.

```
imagename = img.split("/")[-1]
r = requests.get(img)
if r.status_code == 200:
    img_dict = dict(imageName=imagename,content=r.content)
    NAME.append(name)
    IMG.append(img_dict)
```

**UPDATE:**

Get all images of product

```
img_url = product['url']
img_response = requests.get(img_url).json()
if "other_images" in img_response:
    print(img_response['other_images'])
```

O/P:

```
[
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_15.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_16.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_17.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_18.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_19.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_20.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_21.jpg'
][
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_22.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_23.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_24.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_25.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_26.jpg',
  'https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TETBL4974748E953C4/a_27.jpg'
]
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for answer ,but  you didn't get my question, i can also get and save the product from the main page, but what i want is all the images of the product that is inside the  product page,so for example just go to the main page and click on first product, there will be 4 images of the product and i want those 4 images, now come back go on to second product and there is 8 images of the product and i want those 8 images ....and so on